# Regex begin and end with different conditions, but allow a single character

Tags: regex

So I'm stuck on getting this regex right ... Here are the rules:

- It must start with a Letter.
- It can contain ONLY Letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores.
- It must end with a Letter or Number.

I got this far:

```
/\A^[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9\-_]*[A-Z0-9]$\z/i
```

Which seems to work, but doesn't allow a single letter. So `a` would return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex instead to **allow single character input**:

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z0-9]$)[A-Z][\w-]*$/mgi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wX7eO3/1)

`(?=.*?[A-Z0-9]$)` will enforce the rule that string must end with a letter or number.

Comment: Many thanks ... I'm really not going to get my head around Regex Lol ... Even after looking at your demo, I can't see how it works ... But at lest it works :D

Comment: It is mostly same regex you had but with an important change of lookahead I added. That lookahead is `(?=.*?[A-Z0-9]$)` which says match only if there is a letter or number before end anchor `$`.

Comment: could have been simpler and elegant.. lookaheads are powerful but decrease performance..

Comment: Lookaheads are used to enforce rules in regex. Yes this was a simpler case but there are many cases where it cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is expecting atleast two letters because of `[A-Z]+` and `[A-Z0-9]$`..

Use the following:

```
\A^[A-Z](?:[A-Z0-9\-_]*[A-Z0-9])?$\z
        ^^^                     ^
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wX7eO3/2)

Explanation:

- `+` is not required since it is covered by `[A-Z0-9\-_]*`
- included the remaining pattern as optional (with `?`) for one character but compulsory for more than one..

Answer (score 1):

I would go with an alternative like this:

```
^([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][\w-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

The [Demo is here](https://regex101.com/r/tI3bL1/1)

First aternative is a single letter, the second one is letter followed by letter or number or hyphen 0 to unlimited times and ending with letter or number. The parentheses makes a capture group and enforce the alternative to be between start and end of line (`^$`)